# EXT.NET Grid column fields with static names

Tags: ext.net

The grid in EXT.NET displays fields with dynamic names such as #ext-gen1583. I would like to add some automatic tests and for this, I need to have fixed names for fields in the grid.

Is this possible and how to do it, if it is?

I have tried to add an ID("Amount") for example to the X.Column() definition but this is not visible when the grid is rendered.